# Requesting focus from TabHost child view on tab change

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

The below **`TabHost`**, **`NoFocusStealTabHost`**, implements the **`OnAttachStateChangeListener`** interface to implement the tab-focus-steal workaround:

[TabHost tabs steal focus when using Hardware Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669152/android-tabhost-tabs-steal-focus-when-using-hardware-keyboard)

This **`TabHost`** also implements the **`OnTabChangeListener`** interface to listen for tab change events, and calls **`RequestFocus`**() on the first focus-able view found.

Does **`RemoveOnTouchModeChangeListener`**() prevent **`RequestFocus`**() from working? Neither **`RequestFocus`**() or **`RequestFocusFromTouch`**() give the child **`EditText`** focus. It must be explicitly touched in order for (bluetooth) keyboard input to enter into it (which doesn't seem user friendly).

**Layout**

```
<Views.NoFocusStealTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    ...
</Views.NoFocusStealTabHost>
```

**Snippet**

```
LocalActivityManager lam = new LocalActivityManager(Activity, false);
_tabHost = (NoFocusStealTabHost)_thisView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);
lam.DispatchCreate(_bundle);
_tabHost.Setup(lam);
```

**Custom TabHost**

```
public class NoFocusStealTabHost : TabHost, 
    View.IOnAttachStateChangeListener,
    TabHost.IOnTabChangeListener
{
    public NoFocusStealTabHost(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes)
    {
        // Prevent TabHost from stealing focus (legacy android bug)
        AddOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
        SetOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    void View.IOnAttachStateChangeListener.OnViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) { }

    void View.IOnAttachStateChangeListener.OnViewAttachedToWindow(View view)
    {
        // Prevent TabHost from stealing focus (legacy android bug)
        ViewTreeObserver.RemoveOnTouchModeChangeListener(this);
    }

    void IOnTabChangeListener.OnTabChanged(string tabId)
    {
        IList<View> vFocusables = CurrentView.GetFocusables(FocusSearchDirection.Down);

        if (vFocusables != null && vFocusables.Count > 0)
        {
            //vFocusables[0].RequestFocus();
            vFocusables[0].RequestFocusFromTouch();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `RemoveOnTouchModeChangeListener` commented out doesn't help.

Comment: **`CurrentTabView.RequestFocus()`** works better.